# Time returned by CLOCK_BOOTTIME isn't monotonic

Tags: android, android-ndk, clock

In my project I'm facing with strange issue. On my device below code return "test failed" message. Sometimes this happen immediately, sometimes after short while, but always.

```
int main()
{
    while(true)
    {
            static unsigned long long previous;
            timespec time;
            int ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &time);
            if(0 != ret)
            {
                    return 1;
            }

            unsigned long long current = time.tv_sec * 1000000000llu;
            current += time.tv_nsec;

            if(current < previous)
            {
                    std::cerr << "test failed. time stepped back." << std::endl;
                    return 1;
            }
            previous = current;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

What could be possible wrong with this code? Tested on android 4.2.2.

Comment: Print out the values for current and previous -- see if it's taking a short step back or random values.  Maybe print out the components to see if you're getting non-normalized tv_nsec values.  What device is this on?

Comment: This device is Samsung P3110, and I did what you mentioned about printing out values. It seems that value of 'current' is each time 5 seconds lesser than value of 'previous' variable.

Comment: Does it jump back and stay back -- i.e. 5 seconds have been lost and are counted again -- or does it have a single aberrant value?  Have you tried adding a test for large forward jumps -- maybe it actually spat out a time 5 seconds in the future, and you're only noticing when the normal progression resumes.  In any event this is not expected, and I don't see anything in your code that would cause this.  Is CLOCK_MONOTONIC similarly affected?

Comment: Checked. And the result is interesting: 
* first call return right time,
* after one second pass call return time 4 seconds in future,
* and once again - one second pass - this call return time 5 seconds less than previous call,
* and this is repeating continuously,
About CLOCK_MONOTONIC - I will check this later. At this moment I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

> unsigned long long current = time.tv_sec * 1000000000llu;

tv_sec is 32 bit wide. You have to cast it to unsigned long long before multiplying.